# Mapping Tables with shared foreign key in one to one relationship?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

## What is best way to map following classes?

I have classes where communication is "base" class as it contains shared data for either option. There can be only communication to ComSms or to ComEmail. The problem is i am unsure how to proceed with the mapping.
I would like if at all possible use one repository for accessing the Objects.

## Class Set Up

```
public interface ICommunication
    {

    }

public Communication: ICommunication{
   //PK and FK on this item
   public virtual int CommunicationId{get;set;}  
   public virtual string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual string Surname {get;set;}
   public virtual DateTime Date{get;set;}

   //I am expecting to switch on type between ComSms and ComEmail
   public virtual Type {get;set;}
```

}

```
public ComSms : Communication{
   public virtual string Number {get;set;}
   public virtual string Text {get;set;}
}
public ComEmail : Communication{
   public virtual string Subject{get;set;}
   public virtual string Body {get;set;}
   public virtual string Address {get;set;}
}
```

## Database

[image: Simplified Database layout]

## Imagined usage

```
ICommunication smsToSave = new ComSms()
smsToSave.Name = "UserName";
smsToSave.Surname ="UserSurname";
smsToSave.Date = DateTime.Now;
smsToSave.Type = 1;
smsToSave.Number ="123456789";
smsToSave.Text = "Hello boys";
CommunicationRepository.Save(smsToSave)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok 
i have resolved it by separated repositories that handles ever part of it instead

i could not bind it correctly, so chosen to go around the problem.
if you find any way of doing this please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write out any mappings but what you need is a discriminator. This would allow you to say have a `CommunicationType` foreign key in your table that could link to either the `Sms` or `Email` table. The nice thing about discriminators is that NHibernate takes care of everything for you.

And yes, seeing as your aggregate root is `Communication` then you could use one repository for accessing either of your communication types.